# Как и чем реализовать такое выплывающее меню?

Tags: java, android

Все поисковые запросы, что приходили в голову не привели меня к истине. Прошу помощи. У меня есть такая activity

[image: activity]

и мне надо чтобы при клике на какой-то объект появлялось вот это [image: activity 2]

Как и чем мне лучше это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть пара библиотек на гитхабе, позволяющие реализовать подобное. Например [вот эта](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView)

Comment: оставлю  название этой библиотеки тут AnimatedExpandableListView и еще добавлю ссылку на Forked этой библиотеки - https://github.com/lsurvila/AnimatedExpandableListView

Answer (score 0):

ListView не самый лучший вариант нынче, я бы посоветовал вам взглянуть в сторону RecyclerView. [Вот например хорошая библиотека.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)